# Restrictions on an asset level in Content hub

Tags: content-hub

Can we apply a restriction on an asset level to disable or remove the "**create rendition button**", "**download user renditions**" and "**Public link option**"?
I know we can do that on the user group level but the ask is to do it on particular assets.

Comment: Go through to this - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/content-hub-how-setup-asset-type-based-user-permission-yanbin-liu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by applying rules on user group policy(Each user is assigned with some user groups with some permissions on it to access the asset).

I have used OOTB Content Hub taxonomy field "M.DRM.Restricted"(You can create your own new taxonomy)to add a rule on a user group which was assigned to the users that client was using and deselect the permissions which I don't want for the asset.

If "M.DRM.Restricted" field on an assets is "yes" then these restrictions will be applied else it won't. See screenshot for reference:

[image]